# Disable overwriting of all Azure Functions using Visual Studio Code (Python)

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I know that this question has been asked a lot, but I still haven't managed to find a satisfying solution. At my project we have a Python Function App and we would like to be able to deploy functions from different computers (ergo different local projects) without overwriting the existing functions. For the time being, each time we deploy something to the existing Function App, we get the following message:

```
Are you sure you want to deploy to "functionapp"? This will overwrite any previous deployment and cannot be undone.
```

And obviously - if we click on OK, the existing functions are getting overwritten.
People suggest to create a new Function App for each function, but this is not possible, as we don't have the permissions to deploy any new resources on our own and requesting one each time, would simply take ages. Isn't there any other way to do that? Since the Python one can't be developed in the Portal, how are we supposed to create new functions from different computers, without overwriting the existing ones? Are you using any workarounds (Azure DevOps etc.)? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you try to use a single function instance for different function workloads. Independent from the language you use, you need to create a single function instance per workload.

Example: I have 2 workloads:

1. Accept an image via HTTP Request (imgUpload)
2. Resize the image for different formats (imgResize)

So, I create two Azure Function instances in a single App Service Plan with a linked storage account.

```
# Create App Service Plan
az functionapp plan create --name myPlan --resource-group myRG --location "West Europe" --sku B1

# Create storage account
az storage account create --name myStorage --location "West Europe" --resource-group MyRG --sku Standard_LRS

# Create imgUpload function instance
az functionapp create --name imgUpload --storage-account myStorage --plan myPlan --resource-group myRG --os-type Linux --runtime python --runtime-version "3.9" --functions-version 4

# Create imgResize function instance
az functionapp create --name imgResize --storage-account myStorage --plan myPlan --resource-group myRG --os-type Linux --runtime python --runtime-version "3.9" --functions-version 4
```

Now I can push code for image uploading to "imgUpload" and code for image resizing to "imgResize". If necessary I can use deployment slots for a blue-green strategy, but that's not necessary in the beginning.

If you have 10 workloads you want to run in Azure Functions, you need to create 10 different Azure Function instances.

Comment: so there is no other way except of creating new Function Apps every time? Then why do they say that in each function app you can have 100 functions?